# How to use Xetex with Latexila?

Tags: xetex, editors, ubuntu

I am trying to set up Latexila on Ubuntu 12.04 to output using the Xetex engine. I could not find any reference on the web, so I would like to ask you how to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, LateXila supports Xetex by default (1) - or you can easily set it up for yourself (2).

First, be sure you installed `Xetex` and `Latexila` on Ubuntu 12.04/12.10 with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-xetex
sudo apt-get install latexila
```

---

**(1) Work with the default Xetex engine:**

1. Open `Preferences`
2. Tick box next to `Xetex -> PDF`

[image: Preferences]

---

**(2) Set up a custom command to use Xetex directly:**

1. Open `Preferences`
2. Go to `LaTeX` tab
3. Click `New`
4. Enter the commands as shwon in the following screenshot:

[image]